# Json policy script for denying object upload to aws s3 if the object doesn't uses aws s3 encryption or aws:kms encryption

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encryption

Hi I want to create a s3 policy for my bucket which denies the user to upload an object which doesn't uses aws s3 encryption or aws kms encryption (It must use one of the encryption). Here is the link for the policy generator https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html

I have generated this policy.

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1631518070654",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1631518063107",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::webserver7/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"
        },
        "StringNotLike": {
          "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id": "aws:kms"
        }
      },
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

We can Interpret the policy as follows.... "If the object doesn't uses aws s3 encryption **AND** aws:kms encryption then deny the upload.

but we can't use the two encryption at the same time. So I want the policy as follows.

"If the object doesn't uses aws s3 encryption **OR** aws:kms encryption then deny the object upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible to add this kind of policy at the moment. Try using policy for single encryption only.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `OR`, you need to have **two statements**:

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1631518070654",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1631518063107",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::webserver7/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotLike": {
          "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id": "aws:kms"
        }
      },
      "Principal": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt16315180631072",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::webserver7/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"
        }
      },
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for editing the code. But it's still behaving like an "AND" statement. Therefore the upload is getting failed. It will upload if the code works like "OR" statement. Can you make it work like "OR" statement. It would be a huge help.

Comment: @Happycoding Two statements is the OR. If it fails, it means your statements are wrong to start with.